# relocation R_X86_64_32S

Tags: c++, qt, nurbs

Good day, friends! I have a problem with the NURBS library in the QT framework. I am doing a project on QT using the NURBS library. And it was after I added just one command to the code that is directly related to the NURBS library and compiled my code, at the end of the compilation I got this error message:

/usr/bin/ld: /opt/External_Libs/Linux/nurbs++-3.0.11/lib64/8.3.1/libnurbs++.a(barray_hpoint.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_ZTVN4PLib5ErrorE' cannot be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE

/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Please tell me how I can fix this? Maybe some flag or option should be added to the project file (.pro)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: --> `recompile with -fPIE` <--

Comment: More specifically, it is asking you to recompile the library with -fPIE. If you cannot do that, you can try to disable pie making for your main binary instead (something like `-fno-pie -no-pie`).